# iOS account kit email verification. open app link in email gets error

Tags: ios, email-verification

Verifying an email address using account kit the user receives an email that after the user has verified the email they have a option to go back into the app by pressing open app. When pressing open app it says "safari cannot open the page because the address invalid?"

Is there anything I could do client side to make pressing the button open actually open the app not give an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to select target and then info. add url type and then for url scheme I needed to say ak"facebookAppId"